# Sampling data from the pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to sample data from a big dataset.

The dataset is like

```
id      label
1       A
2       B
3       C
4       A
.........
```

Code to generate a sample dataset

```
labels = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N']
df = pd.DataFrame()
N = 300000
weights = [0.350019, 0.209966, 0.126553, 0.100983, 0.053767, 0.039378, 0.029529,
           0.019056, 0.016783, 0.014813, 0.014152, 0.013477, 0.009444, 0.002082]
import random
df['id'] = list(range(1, N+1))
df['label'] = list(random.choices(labels, weights=weights, k=N))

group_dict= df.groupby(['id']).apply(lambda x: list(set(x['label'].tolist()))[0]).to_dict()
df = pd.DataFrame(group_dict.items())
df.columns= ['id','label']
```

The distribution of labels in the dataset is

```
df['label'].value_counts(normalize=True)
```

```
A    0.350373
B    0.209707
C    0.126307
D    0.101353
E    0.053917
F    0.039487
G    0.029217
H    0.018780
I    0.016510
J    0.015083
K    0.014323
L    0.013467
M    0.009530
N    0.001947
```

I created a new column in the dataset

```
df['freq'] = df.groupby('label')['label'].transform('count')
```

When I am trying to sample say `5000` items

```
sampledf = df.sample(n=5000, weights=df.freq,
                          random_state=42)
```

The distribution of the labels in the `sampledf` is not same as that in the `df`

```
A    0.6048
B    0.2198
C    0.0850
D    0.0544
E    0.0190
F    0.0082
G    0.0038
H    0.0020
I    0.0010
K    0.0008
L    0.0008
J    0.0004
```

I am not sure why the distribution is not the same as the actual data frame.

Can anybody help me with what I am missing here?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? You're almost there but we don't actually know how df is defined, for example.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado I have added code to generate the dataset that simulates the issue I am facing.

Comment: Looks great. My answer should still apply - you need to stop using weights when sampling from df. If you just call df.sample you'll be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're re-assigning frequency to the original dataframe, that's probably the issue. Make sure you don't have duplicate labels *and* weights going into your sampling.

Using your summary data I can generate 5000 samples which do have (roughly) the same distribution as the original:

```py
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: summary = pd.DataFrame(
   ...:    [
   ...:        ['A', 0.350019],
   ...:        ['B', 0.209966],
   ...:        ['C', 0.126553],
   ...:        ['D', 0.100983],
   ...:        ['E', 0.053767],
   ...:        ['F', 0.039378],
   ...:        ['G', 0.029529],
   ...:        ['H', 0.019056],
   ...:        ['I', 0.016783],
   ...:        ['J', 0.014813],
   ...:        ['K', 0.014152],
   ...:        ['L', 0.013477],
   ...:        ['M', 0.009444],
   ...:        ['N', 0.002082],
   ...:    ],
   ...:    columns=['label', 'freq']
   ...: )
```

You can sample from the summary table, weighting each ***unique*** label with the frequency in the original dataset:

```py
In [3]: summary.label.sample(
   ...:     n=5000,
   ...:     weights=summary.freq,
   ...:     replace=True,
   ...: ).value_counts(normalize=True)

Out[3]:
label
A    0.3448
B    0.2198
C    0.1356
D    0.0952
E    0.0488
F    0.0322
G    0.0284
H    0.0234
I    0.0168
J    0.0162
K    0.0146
L    0.0140
M    0.0090
N    0.0012
dtype: float64
```

Alternatively, you could simply skip the calculation of the frequencies altogether - pandas will do this for you:

```py
In [7]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(["A", "B", "C", "D"], size=20_000, p=[0.6, 0.3, 0.05, 0.05]), columns=["label"])
In [8]: df.label.sample(5000, replace=True).value_counts(normalize=True)
Out[8]:
A    0.5994
B    0.2930
C    0.0576
D    0.0500
Name: label, dtype: float64
```

The issue with the code in your question is that you end up weighting based on frequency *and* based on the explicit weights (which also account for frequency):

```py
In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(["A", "B", "C", "D"], size=20_000, p=[0.6, 0.3, 0.05, 0.05]), columns=["label"])
In [3]: df['frequency'] = df.groupby('label')['label'].transform('count')
In [4]: df
Out[4]:
        label   frequency
    0   A       11908
    1   A       11908
    2   B       5994
    3   B       5994
    4   D       1033
  ...   ...     ...
19995   A       11908
19996   D       1033
19997   A       11908
19998   A       11908
19999   A       11908
```

The result is roughly equal to the normalized square of each frequency:

```py
In [6]: freqs = np.array([0.6, 0.3, 0.05, 0.05])
In [7]: (freqs ** 2) / (freqs ** 2).sum()
Out[7]:
array([0.79120879, 0.1978022 , 0.00549451, 0.00549451])
```

Comment: I guess `.to_frame().groupby('label').size() / 5000` is equivalent to `.value_counts(normalize=True)`..

Comment: Also, if you consider this MRE: `df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(["A", "B", "C", "D"], size=20_000, p=[0.6, 0.3, 0.05, 0.05]), columns=["label"])`, and apply your way (except I pass unnormalized weights to `.sample` which pandas should normalize), I get: `A    0.7984
B    0.1904
D    0.0062
C    0.0050` which doesn't match the data generating distribution...

Comment: But again - this is because you're passing both weights and repeated values. Pandas is sampling from repeated labels using the repeated weights. So A shows up many times *and* each of those has a higher weight. Either sample with weights or sample from the full dataframe, not both.

Comment: Yes `sampledf = df.sample(n=5000, random_state=42)` did the trick. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for the explanation why the distribution changed. I wish Pandas added this to their docs: `Pandas is sampling from repeated labels using the repeated weights...Either sample with weights or sample from the full dataframe, not both.`